# How to put loading overlay progress bar overing "bottom navigation view" for android (using constraint layout)

Tags: android, kotlin

my id="@+id/loading_overlayView_main" constraintlayout intends to cover the whole screen "including the bottom navigation"

but it doesn't. it seems android adjust it relative to the bottom navigation view.

my four constraint is this

```
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
```

What should I set the layout constraint?

*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation_main"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>
    <fragment
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation_graph" app:defaultNavHost="true"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigation_main"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/loading_overlayView_main"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:background="#000000"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
        <me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialProgressBar.ProgressBar.Large" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*

i expect "@+id/loading_overlayView_main" to cover whole screen (includes the bottom navigation view)

Comment: Why have you added progress bar in a constraint layout, if you want your progress bar to be at center just add the progress bar and put constraints to centralize it, no need to put in constraint layout

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, it is not possible to stretch your layout over bottom navigation. However, what you can do is to follow [Android developer training on enabling fullscreen (immersive) mode for your activities](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive).